# Discrepancy between quantmod Results in R and Online Graphs with EURUSD load with yahoo

Tags: r, finance, quantmod, forex

I'm experiencing an issue with the quantmod package in R while working with EUR/USD data. I use quantmod to retrieve exchange rate data and create charts. However, I've noticed a significant difference between the results I obtain with quantmod and the charts available online for EUR/USD on https://www.boursorama.com.

I'm not sure if there might be an error in my method of using quantmod or if there are specific parameters to consider for obtaining more accurate results.

Has anyone else encountered similar discrepancies with quantmod when working with EUR/USD data? How can I ensure that the results produced by quantmod align better with those displayed on other online platforms?

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Below is my graph using the code compared to the online graph.

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("EURUSD=X", src='yahoo')
chartSeries(`EURUSD=X`,
             type="candlesticks",
             subset='2024-01::2024-03',
             theme=chartTheme('black'))
```

My results:

[image: my result]

Results from website:

[image: online graphique]